# If I run some code from linked javascript file does is execute before or after the dom?

Tags: javascript

Just wondering if I put code in a liked .js file is it the same as adding it in a

```
<script></script>
```

Tag.

And also is it like putting the script at the start or end of the document?

Comment: Do you mean within the head, or somewhere in the `<body>` in both cases (inline and external file)?

Comment: Sorry I mean if I link in the head then is this the same as putting the script in a block in the head? And if I link it at the bottom then is this the same as putting code in a script block in the bottom?

Comment: @Orbling — it makes no difference.

Comment: I recommend placing all JavaScript at the very bottom of your page, right in front of your closing `</body>`-tag. This will enable (some) browsers to render the page while your script is still loading. It saves you some wait time and your page will be visible faster.

Comment: @elusive *some* browsers? Won't *all* browsers load the HTML first if it precedes JS ?

Comment: @Russell Dias: I am pretty sure that older IE-versions had trouble rendering the page without it being completely parsed. I apologize if this is not the case ;)

Comment: Rendering and loading are not the same thing, but all browsers will support progressive rendering for the most part. The exceptions are XHTML (which some engines parse completely and perform well formedness checks on before rendering) and tables (in some browsers, since rerendering can be expensive).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference between using a script embedded in a document and using once srced from an external file is that one has to be loaded from an external source. A srced script at the start of a document is the same as any other script at the start, and one at the end is the same as any other at the end.

All scripts will block parsing of the HTML until the script has been loaded (from within the file or externally) and executed (although that execution might just be setting up event handlers to file later (e.g. `onload`).

(See, however, [the defer attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#adef-defer) but note that browser support isn't universal)

Comment: Correction: External scripts will only block parsing of the html IF they are included in the <head> section. However, if you include them at the end near the </body> tag the html will load and begin parsing.

Comment: If you include them near the end, then they will still block parsing - there just won't be much left to block. Wherever the element is, parsing will pause while it runs (in case, for example, there is a `document.write()` statement).

Answer (score 0):

Not the same when it comes to performance, since for external files, a browser needs to make an additional roundtrip to the server.

But when it comes to execution, a `document.write()` executes exactly after the `script` tag, regardless.

There is however, a `defer` parameter that lets you execute the JS at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript code executes as it is encountered, unless explicitly specified otherwise. There is essentially no technical difference between on page Javascript and external sources.

Currently, if you do not employ some sort of asynchronous loading of JS assets, it is advisable to put them at the bottom of the file (unless of course you need the file in question as the page loads). As script files will essentially load 'back-to-back' and blocking any content that follows.

Most of the time JS is not required until the user begins interacting with the site. Placing JS files at the bottom also enables progressive rendering.

I think Steve Sauders summed it up best:

- Deliver HTML
- Defer JS
- Avoid DOM
- Decorate Later

Answer (score 0):

It executes before DOM (yes, it blocks parsing unless loaded and executed) unless there is [`defer`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/scripts.html#adef-defer) attribute, which standard method to tell UA what there is no `document.write` in the external file. Execution (with probable markup writing to the document stream) takes place immediately after any given `<script>` was encountered by parser.